# evaluating my own functions from list with eval, R5RS

Tags: scheme, lisp, r5rs

I am having problems with this

e.g. i have

```
(define (mypow x) (* x x))
```

and I need to eval expressions from given list. (I am writing a simulator and I get a sequence of commands in a list as an argument)

I have already read that R5RS standard needs to include in function eval as second arg (scheme-report-environment 5), but still I am having issues with this.

This works (with standard function):

```
(eval '(sqrt 5) (scheme-report-environment 5))
```

but this does not:

```
(eval '(mypow 5) (scheme-report-environment 5))
```

It says:

> ../../../../../../usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/kw.rkt:923:25: mypow: undefined;
>    cannot reference undefined identifier

Eventhough simply called mypow in prompt returns:

```
#<procedure:mypow>
```

Any advice, please? (btw I need to use R5RS)

Answer (score 3):

`(scheme-report-environment 5)` returns all the bindings that are defined in the R5RS Scheme standard and not any of the user defined ones. This is by design. You will **never** be able to do what you want using this as the second parameter to `eval`.

The report mentions `(interaction-environment)` which is **optional**. Thus you have no guarantee the implementation has it, but it will have all the bindings from `(scheme-report-environment 5)`

For completeness there is `(null-environment 5)` which only has the bindings for the syntax. eg. `(eval '(lambda (v) "constan) (null-environment 5))` works, but `(eval '(lambda (v) (+ 5 v)) (null-environment 5))` won't since `+` is not in the resulting procedures closure.

**Other ways to get things done**

Usually you could get away without using `eval` alltogether. `eval` should be avoided at almost all costs. The last 16 years I've used `eval` deliberately in production code twice.

By using a `thunk` instead of data:

```
(define todo 
  (lambda () ; a thunk is just a procedure that takes no arguments
    (mypow 5))

(todo) ; ==> result from mypow
```

Now imagine you have a list of operations you'd like done instead:

```
(define ops
  `((inc . ,(lambda (v) (+ v 1)))      ; notice I'm unquoting. 
    (dec . ,(lambda (v) (- v 1)))      ; eg. need the result of the
    (square . ,(lambda (v) (* v v))))) ; evaluation

(define todo '(inc square dec))
(define with 5)

;; not standard, but often present as either fold or foldl
;; if not fetch from SRFI-1 https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html
(fold (lambda (e a)
         ((cdr (assq e ops)) a))
       with
       todo)
; ==> 35 ((5+1)^2)-1
```

Comment: An important addition to this already quite precise answer is that when using `(interaction-environment)` you can also add definitions to the environment, which does not seem to be possible when using `(scheme-report-environment 5)`. For example:
`(eval '(define x 1) (interaction-environment))`
will add an `x` bound to 1 to your current interaction environment.

Comment: @KimMens Yup, but unlike `scheme-report-environment` you have no guarantee `interaction-environment` is present as it is an [optional procedure in the R5RS standard](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_584).

Comment: Yes thanks that was mentioned clearly in the answer